# How to ignore empty dictionary value in Ansible using with_items?

Tags: ansible-2.x

I have a list of dirs that needs to be mounted and by default all servers should get /home mounted. Then some servers get additional mount points. The issue I'm having is, if `aws_mounts.nfs_group` isn't defined, then I get an error stating so. Some servers do not have anything other than the common mounts (/home).

## roles/web/meta/main.yml

```
dependencies:      
  - { role: 'nfs_mounts', nfs_group: "web_mounts" }
```

## roles/perl/meta/main.yml

```
dependencies:      
  - { role: 'nfs_mounts', nfs_group: "perl_mounts" }
```

## roles/nfs_mounts/vars/main.yml

```
aws_mounts:
    common:
      - { source: "nfs-home-{{ nfs_server }}:/",      dest: "/home",                           opts: rw}
    web_mounts:
      - { source: "nfs-webshared-{{ nfs_server }}:/", dest: "/var/cachewebshared",      opts: "rw}
    perl_mounts:
      - { source: "nfs-pdfdocs-{{ nfs_server }}:/",   dest: "/nfs/remote/", opts: "ro" }
      - { source: "nfs-webshared-{{ nfs_server }}:/", dest: "/var/cachewebshared",      opts: "rw}
```

## roles/nfs_mounts/tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Create destination dirs if they do not exist
  file: path="{{ item.dest }}" state=directory
  with_items: 
    - "{{ aws_mounts[nfs_group] }}"
    - "{{ aws_mounts[common] }}"
```

Comment: why are not you using when: some_var is defined ? did i miss anything ?

Comment: I tried that and couldnt get it to work. I was doing `"{{ aws_mounts[nfs_group] }} is not defined"` and it threw an error saying `nfs_group` is not defined.

Comment: Ok, Let me understand a little more. The nfs_group is a list of dictionaries inside aws_mounts dictionary similar to common, web_mounts and perl_mounts ??

Comment: yes. some host only gets the common folders and others get common and whatever is assigned, like the webs and perl servers.

Comment: Did you try with_dict option ?

Comment: As far as i understood, You are looking for with_subelements option. Am i wrong ?

Comment: For servers that do not have `nfs_group` defined, it needs to ignore it.